# CheckComboBox box color

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the WPF Extended CheckComboBox.
I have a template in the app resources in which I've modified a few styling options, however I couldn't find how to change the checkbox color.

Anyone has an idea?

Here is the template I'm using:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type xctk:CheckComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:CheckComboBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" StaysOpen="False">
                        <Grid MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Background="#676767" MaxHeight="{Binding MaxDropDownHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0" Background="#676767">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="#676767" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PART_ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#676767"/>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_DropDownButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Content="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Focusable="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                            <Binding Path="IsDropDownOpen" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                <Binding.Converter>
                                    <xctk:InverseBoolConverter/>
                                </Binding.Converter>
                            </Binding>
                        </ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                            <xctk:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" RenderNormal="False" RenderMouseOver="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_DropDownButton}" RenderPressed="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_DropDownButton}" RenderEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Arrow" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,1C0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 7,0 7,0 7,0 7,1 7,1 7,1 6,1 6,1 6,1 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,3 5,3 5,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,1z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </xctk:ButtonChrome>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFAFAFAF"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type xctk:CheckComboBox}}}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" TargetName="TextBox" Value="False"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" TargetName="TextBox" Value="True"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="TextBox" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Style>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlMouseOverBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlSelectedBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special style for the CheckBoxes. You can style these by adding an implicit `CheckBox` style to the `CheckComboBox`:

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox>
    <xctk:CheckComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </xctk:CheckComboBox.Resources>
</xctk:CheckComboBox>
```